# Display downloadable product URL for order success page for Guests

Tags: orders

Ok so i have got the page working fine for displaying the download links for the downloadable products when the customer is registered and signed in, however when checking out as a guest they are not seeing the links (emails work fine however)

This is my downloadable/block/checkout/list.php

```
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$items = $this->getItems();
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
if (!$orderId) {
    return;
}
$orderItems = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
          ->getCollection()
          ->setOrderFilter($orderId)
          ->getAllIds();
$itemsToRemove = array();
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    if (!in_array($item->getOrderItemId(), $orderItems)) {
    $itemsToRemove[] = $key;
    }
}
foreach ($itemsToRemove as $key) {
    $items->removeItemByKey($key);
}

}

/**
 * Return url to download link
 *
 * @param Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item $item
 * @return string
 */
public function getDownloadUrl($item)
{
return $this->getUrl('downloadable/download/link', array('id' => $item->getLinkHash(), '_secure' => true));
}
```

}

If anyone can give any pointers or want to see any other code please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact I'm not sure what exactly you mean by

> they are not seeing the links

here's my contribution to solve your problem:

There is a seperate block-class `Mage_Downloadable_Block_Checkout_Success` for the success page of downloadable items with a `getOrderHasDownloadable()` function.

The function `getOrderHasDownloadable()` returns `false` if there is a customer-session with customer-id. It seems that downloads are only available for customers, also depending on the fact, that there is customer_id stored in the `downloadable_link_purchased` table.

```
   /**
     * Return true if order(s) has one or more downloadable products
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getOrderHasDownloadable()
    {
        ...
        /**
         * if use guest checkout
         */
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId()) {
            return false;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Try the following:

- check if there is a customer-session present in your block
- check if the link is already generated and saved to the `downloadable_link_purchased_item` table. The link to the downloadable Product gets generated within the `sales_order_item_save_commit_after` event in the `saveDownloadableOrderItem` method in `Mage_Downloadable_Model_Observer`.

You could try to retrieve the download-link via `order-id`, `order-increment-id` in `Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased')` or `purchased-id` reference in `Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')`.